# Send custom push notifications to my app?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I would like to add custom push notifications to my app but would not like to use any services such as parse, urban airship, etc. Is there any way that I would be able to configure this all myself as I have a FTP Server that I could use.

Also, how would I implement this into my app?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Yes. You have to implement the APNS protocols on a server you own or can do Socket IO on.

Comment: See the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1)

Comment: I'd suggest that you use Urban Airship, Parse, etc. unless you have a good reason not to, which it doesn't seem like you do. The APNS protocol is complicated, and running your own server can be very difficult.

Comment: You can buy more. Anyway, bandwidth and servers aren't free. I think you'll find that you'd spend more money on your own server than on Urban Airship.

Comment: But do you have the bandwidth and power for more than 1 million notifications?

Answer (score 0):

It's Ok Everyone! I've found a tutorial. (after about 9 hours of searching the internet) The tutorial, incase anyone else should need it, is here: https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/ Will let people know if it works after I've tried it. Thanks for all your help @Linuxios!